# Comparing a list of strings to itself and getting a list of the first matching characters between them (Python)

Tags: python, list, matching

If I have an array of numbers like this, I need it to print "1" because its the earliest matching character when you compare every string to each other

```
Numbers = ["590", "390", "160", "170", "170"]
```

Running this code I wrote below gives me the number "2" because its the first matching character. Thats the furthest I got and idk what to do anymore.

```
import itertools
import math

qw = "5234"
qe = "4211"
match = list(set(qw.lower()) & set(qe.lower()))
minPoint = match.index(min(match))
match[minPoint]
```

Comment: Paste actual code you've tested to reproduce the problem you describe.  Integers don't have a `.lower()` method.  Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Its code I've written, with some libraries, updated it

Comment: Edit your question and post the code there, not in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Your `set` idea goes in the right direction, but you probably want to `zip` first, because that groups the digits you want to compare together.
The most convenient way is then to use the `collections.Counter` class

```
import collections

for j, row in enumerate(zip(*Numbers)):
    counts = collections.Counter(row)
    best = counts.most_common(1)[0]
    if best[1] > 1:
        print("Found {} occurrences of {} in position {}".format(best[1], best[0], j))
        break
else:
    print('No repeats found')
```